# Django and old fashioned SQL queries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, python-2.7

I have a model as follows:

```
class call_log(models.Model):
    call_from = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    call_to = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    end_time = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True, default=0)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True, default=0)
```

It has records for each individual call made by (different) numbers and sip endpoints.

The SQL query I want to run is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(call_from) AS start, sum(total) AS total 
FROM polls_call_log GROUP BY start;
```

How do I write this in / for django?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count
call_log.objects.values('call_from').annotate(Count('total'))
```